# Socket.io events not received (nginx reverse proxy, server to client)

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io, reverse-proxy

I have a nodejs socket.io app running under nginx reverse proxy.

My nginx configuration is as follows:

```
location ~ ^/(online|socket\.io) {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8888;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

This seems to work, and my nodejs app picks up the connection fine. On the server side socket.io I have the following:

```
io.of('/online').on('connection', function(socket){
```

This seems to work fine, and the 'connection' event is firing

The problem arises when I try to emit an event from the server to the client:

```
socket.join("users");
io.sockets.in("users").emit("got_users",users);
```

The 'got_users' event is not being picked up by the client. On the client side I have the following:

```
a4e.socket=io.connect('http://www.example.com/online');
```

This seems to work fine, but then:

```
a4e.socket.on("got_users",function(online_users){
```

This doesn't pick up the "got_users" event, no matter what I try.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured this out, the following line:

```
io.sockets.in("users").emit("got_users",users);
```

Should be replaced with:

```
io.of("/online").in("users").emit("got_users",users);
```

Then it works.

Comment: Thanks @praine. I was about to get lost and hopeless.

Comment: ^^ The above works. Here is how I did it directly from the connection:
const httpIo = socket(httpServer, { origins: '*:*' });
httpIo.of('/yourProxyurlhere').on('connection', (currentSocket) => {Your Code Here})

Comment: could you provide a better explanation for this? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: @Lhew Check out the socket.io documentation on namespaces: https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: This looks dubious to me... because the documentation says that '_The namespace is an implementation detail of the Socket.IO protocol, and is not related to the actual URL of the underlying transport, which defaults to /socket.io/…._' and even though, you use this /online/ path on Nginx. I follow the documentation by using path, like `socket = io(http, {path: '/online/'})`. Even though this implementation of yours doesn't make too much sense I'll try anyway. Thanks for your help.