# socket.io fails any socket.emit running on nginx reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, docker, sockets, nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a node app that is running in a dockerized environment just fine. It runs all fine over HTTP and locally. Only when I use Nginx reverse proxy, the socket.emit doesn't return anything.

My Nginx config:

```
   location /verification/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3005/;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
   }
```

my socket connection (client):

```
const socket = io( 
   'https://mywebsite.com',
   { path:  + '/verification/socket.io/', 
     secure: true, 
     rejectUnauthorized: false 
   }, fn)
```

My server config:

```
const io = socket(http, {path: '/socket.io/'});
```

Comment: See if this similar question helps you out? https://stackoverflow.com/a/42039165/12989672

Comment: Thanks for the comment but it didn't work actually. Even though I've learned something from it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I've come to a solution with this. I've implemented the room scenario myself and it's been working well. For so, I just implemented the following:

```js
const clients = {};
io.to('/verification/').connection(function(){
   
  clients[socket.id] = {room: null, id: socket.id};
  socket.on('message', function(payload){
      if(payload.intent === 'join'){
         clients[socket.id] = {...clients[socket.id], room: payload.room};
      }
  });

  //and to broadcast messages:

   
   Object.values(clients)
       .map(client => {
          socket.to(client.id).emit('message', 'foo message')
       })
})
```